# Running commands on several files and giving each output a unique name

Tags: bash, shell, files

I want to run a script on all the files in a folder like this:

```
sh script.sh *.fasta > output
```

however I want the outputs to be in individual files for every input. So instead of getting 5 files through the command and putting them all into a file called "output" is there a way to have the outputs be the name of the file with a suffix at the end like "_output"?

So if I had 3 files like:

```
file1.fasta
file2.fasta
file3.fasta
```

Is there a way I could run a command like this:

```
sh script.sh *.fasta
```

and output the new files like this for each input:

```
file1_new.fasta
file2_new.fasta
file3_new.fasta
```

I tried the command:

```
sh script.sh *.fasta > *_output.fasta
```

But it didn't work, I also tried assigning all the files of interest to a variable like this, with he idea that maybe I could somehow rename the outputs if I first assigned them to a variable:

```
allthefiles= *.fasta
```

But that didn't work either. I don't know what to call this question, so sorry if it's been asked already! How do I run several files through a command and have a new output for each input?

Comment: Use a [`for` loop](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/classic_for)...

Comment: Related: [How can I safely create and access temp files from shell scripts?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/235985/135943)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal shell, *within a script* or function:

```
for file in "$@" ; do
  if true; do 
     # do some work which reads from stdin
     # and outputs to stdout
  fi > "${file}_output.fasta" < "$file"
done
```

Or the more conventional (but possibly tedious)

```
for file in "$@" ; do
  output="${file}_output.fasta"
  some_program $file > $output
  another_program_appends $file >> $output
done
```

You can also do something like this with awk:

```
$ awk '{ print substr($0,1,20) >> FILENAME "_output.fasta" }' *fasta
```

The awk script outputs the first 20 characters of each line of each input file, saving the output as you expected.

Comment: Just use `{ ... }` in place of the `if` statement.

Comment: I know. I was being demonstrative. The `{ ... }` is more concise but doesn't explain.

Comment: What does the `if` explain? You're introducing a conditional with no actual condition. Its only purpose is to group commands in order to share a file for standard output, and that's exactly what braces are for.

Comment: To demonstrate that there is nothing special about `{ ... }` and that any shell control block can be used to redirect input/output for that block. I am 98% certain that my explanation is superior to yours by 0.000001%.

Answer (score 5):

```
for f in *.fasta; do 
    sh script.sh "$f" > "${f%.*}_output.fasta"; 
done

# ${f%.*} strips a shortest match of `.*` from the end of "$f"
# (= strips .fasta)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [make](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software))!

Write a file called `GNUmakefile` with the content below, but where I put the character  ↦, put a tab instead (it has to be a tab, it can't be spaces).

```
all: $(filter-out %_output.fasta,$(wildcard *.fasta))

%_output.fasta: %.fasta
↦./script.sh $< >$@.tmp
↦mv $@.tmp $@
```

Now, to regenerate all the files, type `make`. As a bonus, if an input file hasn't changed since the output file was last generated, `script.sh` won't run again. If you're actively modifying `script.sh` and you want to regenerate the output files, add `script.sh` after `%.fasta`, this way the files will also be regenerated if the script has changed.

Explanations:

- The first line specifies what to do when you run `make all`. Since it's the first line (the first *target*, in makefile terminology), running `make` with no argument does the same thing.
- The part after `all:` generates the list of names of `.fasta` files in the current directory, and removes the ones called `_output.fasta`.
- The line `%_output.fasta: %.fasta` starts a *rule* that explains how to generate a file whose name ends with `_output.fasta` (the *target*) from the corresponding `.fasta` file (a *dependency*).
- The following tab-indented lines are the commands to run to generate the files.
- The first line transforms the first dependency (`$<`) into a `.tmp` file.
- The second line renames the `.tmp` file into the target file (`$@`). The reason for this two-step process is that if the generation is interrupted for any reason, this won't leave an invalid target file behind.

Note: I assume that you're using Linux. If not, you may need to install GNU make and run that instead of your system's default `make` command, if you want to use the code above.

If you used a different extension for the output files, it would make things a little easier.

```
all: $(patsubst %.fasta,%.out,$(wildcard *.fasta))

.SUFFIX: .out .fasta
.fast.out:
↦./script.sh $< >$@.tmp
↦mv $@.tmp $@
```

If you replace the first line by the explicit list of files (`all: foo.out bar.out`) then the file can be called `Makefile` and will run with any implementation of `make`.

Comment: `make` also lets you use `make -j 8` to run 8 jobs in parallel, useful if your tasks aren't already multi-threaded.

Answer (score 3):

You can do them in parallel with ... gnu parallel:

```
parallel "sh script.sh {} > {}.out" ::: *
```

Comment: Can you explain the `:::` part?

Comment: It's not a unix thing, it's just how GNU parallel says "ok, here are your args". You can also pipe them in, I believe. More info: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one line solution

```
find ./ -name "*.fasta" -exec sh -c 'script.sh ${0} > ${0}.log' {} \;
```

In short, it finds the files you want, and execs your script on them. The point of using `sh -c` is so that the redirect character `>` is not interpreted directly.

Comment: @Otheus, thanks for the tip with multiple `{}`, I've had issues with it before but it seems to work.  However this still needs sh -c because otherwise the shell will pick up the redirection `>` and try to output to `{}.log`