# How to invoke vim editor and pipe output to bash

Tags: vim, pipe, stdout

Sometimes I need to write text and then pipe that text into another command. My usual workflow goes something like this:

```
vim
# I edit and save my file as file.txt
cat file.txt | pandoc -o file.pdf # pandoc is an example 
rm file.txt
```

I find this cumbersome and seeking to learn bash scripting I'd like to make the process much simpler by writing a command which fires open an editor and when the editor closes pipe the output of the editor to stdout. 
Then I'd be able to run the command as `quickedit | pandoc -o file.pdf`.

I'm not sure how this would work. I already wrote a function to automate this by following the exact workflow above plus some additions. It generates a random string to act as a filename and passes that to vim when the function is invoked. When the user exits vim by saving the file, the function prints the file to the console and then deletes the file.

```
function quickedit {
    filename="$(cat /dev/urandom | env LC_CTYPE=C tr -cd 'a-f0-9' | head -c 32)"
    vim $filename
    cat $filename
    rm $filename
}
# The problem:
# => Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal
```

The problem I soon encountered is that when I do something like `quickedit | command` vim itself can't be used as an editor because all output is constrained to the pipe.

I'm wondering if there are any workarounds to this, so that I could pipe the output of my `quickedit` function. The suboptimal alternative is to fire up a separate editor, say sublime text, but I really want to stay in the terminal.

Comment: From within vim, issue the command `:w !pandoc -o file.pdf` ?  (Note: the space between `w` and `!` is essential.)

Comment: Ok - that's great. I didn't know you could pipe vim output from within vim itself. This serves my purposes, but for my future knowledge, is it possible to solve my problem exactly how I intended it to be solved?

Comment: Can you post your function? What do you mean when you talk about the problem you soon encountered (second last paragraph)? I don't get that.

Comment: As an aside, you should [use `mktemp`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/235985/135943) rather than reinventing it in insecure fashion.

Comment: As a new bash user, what are the security dangers of reinventing mktemp?

Comment: theideasmith Gilles' answer in the post linked to by @Wildcard discusses it.

Comment: Also, do check out sister site [vi.se], if you're interested in learning to use Vim better.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

[`vipe`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/vipe.1.html) is a program for editing pipelines:

```
command1 | vipe | command2
```

You get an editor with the complete output of `command1`, and when you exit, the contents are passed on to `command2` via the pipe.

In this case, there's no `command1`. So, you could do:

```
: | vipe | pandoc -o foo.pdf
```

Or:

```
vipe <&- | pandoc -o foo.pdf
```

`vipe` picks up on the `EDITOR` and `VISUAL` variables, so you can use those to get it to open Vim.

If you've not got it installed, `vipe` is available in the `moreutils` package; `sudo apt-get install moreutils`, or whatever your flavour's equivalent is.

Comment: For Mac users who've arrived here: `moreutils` is available in Homebrew.

Comment: For FreeBSD users: `moreutils` is available to be installed via [pkg(8)](http://man.freebsd.org/pkg/8).

Comment: It's possible to do `command xyz | vipe | bash` (or other shell) and during the `vipe` editing process you can edit the stdin into a command that will be run when you save&quit.

Answer (score 24):

You can do this from within Vim:

```
:w !pandoc -o file.pdf
```

Or even write the buffer into a complex pipeline:

```
:w !grep pattern | somecommand > file.txt
```

And then you can exit Vim without saving:

```
:q!
```

---

However, considering your specific use case, there is probably a better solution by using `vi` as your command line editor.  Assuming you use `bash`:

```
set -o vi
```

This sets your keybindings to `vi`.  So you can edit your commands right on the command line with basic `vi` keybindings by pressing `<Esc>` and then typing `vi` commands such as `x`, `cw`, etc.  (You can get back in insert mode by pressing `i`.)

Even better, and more relevant to this question, **you can open Vim to create your command line content directly.**  Just type `<Esc>v` and you will get an empty Vim buffer.  When you save and exit, that *is* the command on your command line and it is immediately run.  This is much much more flexible than editing on the command line directly as you can write a whole mini-script if you want.

---

So, for example, if you want to write some tricky text and pipe it into pandoc immediately, you could just type:

```
<Esc>v
```

Then edit the Vim buffer until you have something like:

```
cat <<EOF | pandoc -o file.pdf
stuff for pandoc
more stuff for pandoc
EOF
```

Then save and exit (with `:x`) and the whole thing will be run as a shell command.

It will also be available in your shell's command history.

Comment: If you prefer to keep the Emacs key bindings, you can still use Vim to edit command lines by setting the `EDITOR` environment variable to `vim` and pressing `Ctrl-X` followed by `Ctrl-E` while editing the command line.

Answer (score 20):

### Running in a pipeline

Try:

```
quickedit() (  trap 'rm ~/temp$$' exit; vim ~/temp$$ >/dev/tty; cat ~/temp$$ )
```

The key is that, to be able to use `vim` normally, `vim` needs stdout to be the terminal.  We accomplish that here with the redirect `>/dev/tty`.

For purposes of security, I put the temporary file in the user's home directory.  For more on this, see [Greg's FAQ Question 062](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/062).  This eliminates the need to use an obscure file name.

#### Example:

When `vim` opens, I type `This function succeeded.` and save the file.  The result on the screen looks like:

```
$ quickedit | grep succeeded
This function succeeded.
```

Even though the output of `quickedit` is redirected to a pipeline, `vim` still works normally because we have given it direct access to `/dev/tty`.

### Running a program from within vim

As I mentioned in the comments, vim can pipe a file to a command.  From within vim, for example, issue the command `:w !pandoc -o file.pdf` (Note: the space between w and ! is essential).

Comment: Nice answer. This one directly addresses the user's question, and offers a quick and elegant solution: redirect vim to /dev/tty! Simple!

Comment: I'm using Zsh; `trap '...' exit` fails but `trap '...' EXIT` appears to work.
I don't know much about trapping, but my general approach for temporary files  is to use `mktmp [--suffix=...]`. Also, `vim <outfile> -c '...' >/dev/tty` runs as normal until the file is loaded, then executes the given command chain, including `:wq` if you want to skip the editing phase. I also used `set | grep -a EXIT` and found `signals=(EXIT ... DEBUG)`.

Answer (score 10):

Make sure that `vim` is set as your default editor (e. g. `export EDITOR=vim` in your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`.  Then, at any prompt, you can type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>.  This will open your current command line in your configured editor (e. g. `vim`).  Make your edits, save and exit, and the command will be executed as though you had typed it on the command line, including pipelines and the like.

Answer (score 0):

vim, vi, vile, emacs, all have support to pipe their buffer or even pieces of buffer (e.g line selection) into filters and commands. This is powerful to either help you in editing files, as the classic utilities become editing assistants, or to perform tasks from within the editor, using text files to memorize complete commands that you execute by cursor selection or motion, and so on.
The `!` character is a typical trigger for that. Read vi manual and look for this entry.
With a portable customized configuration, such editors become a handy off-road toolkit useable despite poor network or graphical capabilities, stable over time (life-time). They are worth learning deeply, one of them may become your best friend.