# How do I prompt for user input using $EDITOR from a script?

Tags: shell-script, user-input

I want to have an input mechanism akin to `git commit`. When the script is run, it should open an editor to edit a temporary file, use this file as my input, and then get rid of the file.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is with the the builtin `read` command.

```
 read -r -p 'Please enter your favorite editor' editor
 echo "You have enter $editor"
```

Now the value is in the `$editor"` variable, next step would be to test if there is indeed an editor that is installed or within your PATH.

```
if type "$editor" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
   command "$editor" ENTER_THE_FILE_YOU_WANT_TO_EDIT
else
   echo "$editor no such file or directory!" >&2
   exit 127
fi
```

see

```
help type
help command
```

The 127 exit status is what the shell will exit if there is no executable, alias, function. have a look at

```
 man 1p exit
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`vipe`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/282384/70524) with nothing (or some default text) as input:

```
% foo=$(echo | vipe)
# opens an editor, I add `foo bar`
% echo "$foo"
foo bar
```

`vipe` will take care of creating the temporary file and deleting it.