# Is there a way to pipe to a visual editor and then continue the pipeline?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, text-processing

I know that some command-line programs can open visual editors like Sublime in a "wait mode" which opens the editor, lets you edit, and on-close it resumes the program with the file contents (like git commit). I'm wondering if there's any way to write a pipeline like this:

`cat $file | sort | [open sublime in wait mode] | grep abc`

Ie, I want to take the output of one command, open it in an editor, let me make edits, then it continues the pipeline with the file contents.

Thanks!

Comment: Dunno about GUI editors, but there's `vipe` for command-line ones: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/282384/70524 If you can figure out the right way to inoke Sublime to make it wait, setting the `EDITOR` or `VISUAL` environment variable to that should work for `vipe`.

Comment: Found it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33132018/2072269: `EDITOR='subl --wait'`

Comment: You don't need to `cat` into `sort`, or to `cat` in anything actually. `sort`, as any program, can take a file as argument. `sort $file | vipe | grep abc` will do the work.