# Is there a way to have nano to pipe output to another program's input?

Tags: pipe, encryption, nano

I have a program A that pipes its input to nano this way: `program_a | nano -`. I want to make edits with nano and pipe it again to another program B, without having nano to write anything on the disk (The processed data is sensitive, and I want it to be only written as encrypted or processed within RAM; program B is actually an encryption program).

In order to achieve my goal, I know of solutions requiring the creation of a *tmpfs* on the RAM, this I would like to avoid.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to invoke vim editor and pipe output to bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282366/how-to-invoke-vim-editor-and-pipe-output-to-bash). Question is about `vim`, but `vipe` will work with any editor set as `EDITOR`.

Comment: ah no, I see that both nano and vim use a temp file ...

Comment: `vipe` would actually fit my needs... Where did you read about the use of temporary files by editors though? I know that `nano` can dump its buffer into `.save` files when receiving something like a `SIGTERM`, but I thought it was not doing it everytime.