# How to check if several files exist?

Tags: shell-script, wildcards

I have a shell script that looks for a file, `/tmp/bbsnode1`, and if the existence of that file is true, it deletes it. What I'd like to do is if multiple files exist (`/tmp/bbsnode2`, `/tmp/bbsnode3`, and `/tmp/bbsnode4`), delete all of them. **But only delete them if all of them exist.**

Here's what I have so far:

```
if [ -f /tmp/bbsnode1 ]
then
/usr/bin/rm /tmp/bbsnode1
fi
```

Comment: Relevant: [How can I safely create and access temp files from shell scripts?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/235985/135943)

Comment: Why do you need to check the existence of the file before deleting it? This seems like an X-Y problem.

Comment: As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If one of the answers *solved your problem*, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of its text, which means [Yes, this answer is the most useful of all](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: same question on stackoverflow: [Check if a file exists with wildcard in shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363441/check-if-a-file-exists-with-wildcard-in-shell-script)

Answer (score 11):

I would use a shell **function** for this, rather than a script:

```
rm-all-or-none() {
  for f; do
    [ -f "$f" ] ||
      { printf '%s is not an existing file, no files removed\n' "$f" >&2
        return 1;}
  done
  rm -fv -- "$@"
}
```

Then I would call it using brace expansion, rather than a glob.  Globs only expand to files that *exist*, but in this case we want to specify the files and only remove them if *all* of them exist:

```
rm-all-or-none /tmp/bbsnode{1..4}
```

---

Longer equivalent version:

```
rm-all-or-none() {
  for f in "$@"; do
    if [ -f "$f" ]; then
      :
    else
      printf '%s is not an existing file, no files removed\n' "$f" >&2
      return 1
    fi
  done
  rm -fv -- "$@"
}
```

---

Also see:

- [In Bash, when to alias, when to script, and when to write a function?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/30925/135943)

Comment: That is an question for (a) Wildcard !!

Comment: I hadn't noticed that detail. :D

Comment: I don't know if "golfing" the code is appropriate here... why not write:  `for f in "$@"; do` instead?

Comment: I would agree with @Oliver here, I am pretty knowledgeable in bash, but it took a few glances myself to catch everything going on. Very few people are aware that you could omit `in "$@"` in this case, IMHO. I'd even change the use of `||` to a regular `if` statement to make it easier to pick up. I do like the use of -- though on rm. I often omit that, but it can be very important and makes the script much more rugged when used long-term.

Comment: @penguin359, the purpose here is to *increase* the number of people who are aware that you can omit `in "$@"`.  ;)  I wasn't trying to golf, I just tend to prefer `|| { ...;}` for negative conditions with an error-exit action associated.  But I've now added a longer form of the function as well.

Comment: @Wildcard part of my concern was that there was no explanation for the `for f;` and not everyone would be able to pick up on it, but seeing it next to the longer version makes it very clear indeed! Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You could use an arbitrary command like `ls` to check for the files and delete them in one line

```
ls /tmp/bbsnode{1,2,3,4} &>/dev/null && rm /tmp/bbsnode{1,2,3,4}
```

Note that in general it's unsafe to do such things in /tmp because any other user could create conflicting files with the same names.

A short explanation:

The return value of `ls` is non-zero if one of the files does not exist. The `{1,2,3,4}` is brace expansion: it expands to a string for each number: so `/tmp/bbsnode{1,2,3,4}` is the same as `/tmp/bbsnode1 /tmp/bbsnode2 /tmp/bbsnode3 /tmp/bbsnode4`. The `&&` executes the next command only if the previous command has a zero return value, and so here `rm` is only executed if all 4 files exist. Finally, the `&> /dev/null` suppresses the output of `ls` (`&>` redirected both `stdout` and `stderr`, `/dev/null` gets rid of it).

Below another solution with shell builtins only. It's similar to what others have answered but without an extra function or script:

```
set -- /tmp/bbsnode{1,2,3,4}
(for f; do test -f "$f" || exit; done) && rm -- "$@"
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanation?

Comment: @nomanpouigt, see `LESS='+/Brace Expansion' man bash` and also [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/135943)

Answer (score 3):

In this particular case you could do:

```
set -- file[1-4]
[[ $# -eq 4 ]] && rm -f -- "$@"
```

This `set`s the argument list to the file names that match any of `file1`, `file2`, `file3` or `file4`<sup>1</sup> then `rm`s those files only if the number of arguments equals 4, that is, if all files exist.

---

<sup>1: for simplicity, I use `file` instead of `/tmp/bbsnode`</sup>

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is via two commands: `set -e` and `stat`

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e # make script exit if there's errors

main()
{
    stat "$@"
    rm "$@"
}

main "$@"
```

#### How this works

The key here is `set -e`. It makes the script exit *immediately* if errors are encountered. `stat` takes on the list of all the files you give it. If there is a file missing, it will return exit status 1, which signifies error. That way, your script will get to `rm` part *if and only if* there's no errors encountered with `stat`

#### Side-notes

- you can use `stat "$@" > /dev/null` to suppress output to screen
- Using `main()` function isn't required, this is just stylistic preference of the author.
- as rudimeier pointed out in the comments, you can also use a one-liner with these two commands: `stat "$@" && rm "$@"`.

#### Test Run:

```
bash-4.3$ chmod +x remove_all_if_exist.sh 
bash-4.3$ touch /tmp/{file1,file2}
bash-4.3$ ls /tmp/file*
/tmp/file1  /tmp/file2
bash-4.3$ ./remove_all_if_exist.sh  /tmp/file1 /tmp/file2 /tmp/file3
  File: '/tmp/file1'
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 3423307     Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/ xieerqi)   Gid: ( 1000/ xieerqi)
Access: 2016-11-04 17:44:06.587438784 -0600
Modify: 2016-11-04 17:44:06.587438784 -0600
Change: 2016-11-04 17:44:06.587438784 -0600
 Birth: -
  File: '/tmp/file2'
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 3423308     Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/ xieerqi)   Gid: ( 1000/ xieerqi)
Access: 2016-11-04 17:44:06.587438784 -0600
Modify: 2016-11-04 17:44:06.587438784 -0600
Change: 2016-11-04 17:44:06.587438784 -0600
 Birth: -
stat: cannot stat '/tmp/file3': No such file or directory
bash-4.3$ ls /tmp/file*
/tmp/file1  /tmp/file2
bash-4.3$ ./remove_all_if_exist.sh  /tmp/file1 /tmp/file2
  File: '/tmp/file1'
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 3423307     Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/ xieerqi)   Gid: ( 1000/ xieerqi)
Access: 2016-11-04 17:44:06.587438784 -0600
Modify: 2016-11-04 17:44:06.587438784 -0600
Change: 2016-11-04 17:44:06.587438784 -0600
 Birth: -
  File: '/tmp/file2'
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 3423308     Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/ xieerqi)   Gid: ( 1000/ xieerqi)
Access: 2016-11-04 17:44:06.587438784 -0600
Modify: 2016-11-04 17:44:06.587438784 -0600
Change: 2016-11-04 17:44:06.587438784 -0600
 Birth: -
bash-4.3$ ls /tmp/file*
ls: cannot access '/tmp/file*': No such file or directory
bash-4.3$
```

---

#### Alternative with python:

```
python -c 'import sys,os;f=sys.argv[1:];c=[os.path.exists(a) for a in f]; l = len(c)*[True]; result = [os.unlink(a) for a in f] if l == c else False; print result' /tmp/file1 /tmp/file2
```

- get list of command line-arguments with `sys.argv[1:]`
- build a list of true-false values if files exist
- if all files return True, unlink(remove) them

Comment: Very very noisy.  Why not suppress all output from the `stat` command?  Also, regarding your preference for `main()` in a shell script: See the hacker section of [Evolution of a Programmer](http://www.ariel.com.au/jokes/The_Evolution_of_a_Programmer.html).  ;)

Comment: @Wildcard yep, very noisy, that's why I've added  "Side Notes" section ( which you probably missed ) which does mention redirection to `/dev/null`. I just prefer giving the OP full-test, so to speak, so that they know it works. Also, about `main()` , see this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/313256/85039 ;)

Comment: I think more simple would be  `stat "$@" && rm "$@"` without `set -e`, which would be the same like in my answer.

Comment: @rudimeier sure, that can be done as well.

Comment: Thank you all, for your suggestions. They're greatly appreciated. But I'll stick with the first answer, it does what it's supposed to do, regardless of how many characters the command(s) are. So, again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this script, named `removing_group`

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

function check {
    while (( "$#" )) ; do
        if [ -f "$1" ] ; then
            # echo "The file $1" ;
            shift ;
        else
            # echo "The's no file $1";
            return 1
        fi
    done
    return 0
}

if check $@; then
    while (( "$#" )) ; do
        # echo "Remove $1" ;
        rm "$1" ;
        shift ;
    done
fi
```

The `check` function checks all of it arguments to be regular files.  If the next file isn't exist, the function returns `1` and nothing happens.  If all of the files exists, then returned `0` will process `if check $@`, which will remove files one-by-one.  The files for checking and removing described as parameters in the command line, for example

```
./removing_group /tmp/bbsnode1 /tmp/bbsnode2 /tmp/bbsnode3 /tmp/bbsnode4
```

or

```
./removing_group /tmp/bbsnode{1,2,3,4}
```