# Is it possible to add some text at beginning of a file in CLI without making new file?

Tags: text-processing, sed, editors

I have two files; `file1` containing -

```
hello world
hello bangladesh
```

and `file2` containing -

```
 Dhaka in Bangladesh
 Dhaka is capital of Bangladesh
```

I want to update `file2` as -

```
hello world
hello bangladesh 
Dhaka in Bangladesh
Dhaka is capital of Bangladesh
```

This is done by -

```
cat file1 file2 >> file3
mv file3 file2
```

But, I don't want to create a new file. I guess using `sed` it may be possible.

Comment: Almost all tools that edit in-place create a temporary file, just so you know.

Comment: @don_crissti, a valid point, but such tools do so a lot more safely than many shell script authors.  Also relevant: [How can I safely create and access temp files from shell scripts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/235985/135943)

Comment: @don_crissti That means if I want to do this for keeping hard disk usage same at that time, this doesn't work.

Comment: @alhelal, how big is this file, anyway?  Since you're not deleting file1, you **can't** keep your hard disk usage the same.  Perhaps you should append `file2` to `file1` and then move it over the top of `file2`.  That way you don't create a *new* file, you just overwrite the old.

Comment: @Wildcard I am sure that this increase hard disk usage after doing this, but concern is in processing time.

Comment: @alhelal, aha.  Well, in common UNIX/Linux filesystems, appending a couple of lines to a multi-gigabyte file is **much, much** faster than PRE-pending those lines to the same file.  In the latter case, in most if not all filesystems, the entire file needs to be rewritten.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure it's possible.

<sub>(Unless you are also concerned about temporary files being potentially created "under the hood," as virtually all text editors work that way.  I don't say it is flatly impossible to avoid any possibility under-the-hood temp file creation, but it's not covered in this answer.)</sub>

```
printf '%s\n' '0r file1' x | ex file2
```

This is a POSIX-compliant command using [`ex`, the POSIX-specified non-visual predecessor to `vi`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html).

`printf` is only used here to feed a command to the editor.  What `printf` outputs is:

```
0r file1
x
```

`x` is save and exit.

`r` is "read in the contents of the named file."

`0` specifies the line number after which the read-in text should be placed.

Comment: This works. But, Is this increase my hard-disk usage?

Comment: @alhelal, that depends on the file sizes and your memory utilization.  Obviously since you're not deleting `file1` your hard disk usage will have a net increase (although even that's not actually true in all cases).  But will you have a *temporary* increase in hard disk utilization?  That's a different layer of abstraction, not answerable from the data given.

Comment: Does this create temporary file?

Comment: @alhelal, again, that depends on the file size and your memory utilization.

Comment: If I have enough memory space for putting `file1/file2/?` then it donesn't create temporary file. Am  I right? or Do you mean any complex thing?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar enough with the C code of common `ex` implementations to give a definitive answer to that—but what you describe is what I would *guess,* as well.  Don't take it as gospel truth, but that is *probably* the case.  :)

Comment: In modern systems `ex` is usually implemented as part of `vim`. `vim` creates a swap file. I'm not sure if `ex` does same but if you add `-n` to a `ex`/`vim` invocation that will prevent swap file creation. So you might want to do that depending on what your requirements are.

Answer (score 3):

There aren't a lot of ways to modify files in place using standard tools. Even if they appear to do so they may be using temporary files (i.e. GNU `sed -i`).

`ex` on the other hand, will do the trick:

```
 ex -n -c '0r file2' -c wq file1
```

`ex` is a line editor and `vim` evolved from it so these commands may look familiar. `0r filename` does the same thing as `:0r filename` in `vim`: insert the specified file after the given address (line number). The line number here is 0 which is a kind of virtual line that represents the line before line 1. So the file will be inserted before any existing text.

Then we have `wq` which saves and quits.

If you notice the comment below about this being "very brittle" take it with a grain of salt. If you want to use this in a script just be sure to do proper pre-condition validation (files exist, are readable/writable, etc.). Good scripters would be doing that anyways.

**Update:** I've added `-n` to address OP's concerns about avoiding any temporary file creation. Assuming that your `ex` is implemented as part of `vim` (as is the case on most modern systems) this flag will suppress the normal swap file creation that `vim` does.

Comment: Note that (a) this is not fully POSIX compliant as `ex` is not mandated to support `+command` syntax, and also (b) it is very brittle if used in scripting as the non-existence of `file2` will hang `ex` up waiting on user input.  See [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/414407/135943) for a version that avoids these pitfalls.

Comment: @alhelal Sure. Does it make sense now?

Comment: Good edit, but just FYI it is still not script-worthy.  If `file2` is not readable `ex` will still wait forever.  If `ex` is unable to write the changes to `file1` it will wait forever.  *Any* error will make `ex` wait for user input.  For a scripted use of `ex`, you should never do otherwise than feeding it commands in a way that guarantees it will receive an EOF (such as using a pipe or heredoc).

Comment: Do you add a "not POSIX compliant" comment to every answer that's not POSIX compliant. Because the convention I've noticed is the inverse: the person posting the answer indicates POSIX compliance. You can assume the rest aren't. I'm thinking of that "o"-word again.

Comment: Unless it's stated in the answer that it's not portable, or unless (even better) it's stated on which specific systems the command works, then yes, I usually do.  If you say, "on Linux systems" or "using GNU Awk" or similar, then obviously you don't need to say it's not POSIX-compliant.  I picked up the habit *from this site* of being very specific about where a command will or will not work—and it's saved me a lot of trouble, so I do such comments myself just as I've seen others do.  Feel free to ping me in chat; let's not clutter up the comments.

Comment: IOW it's not just about POSIX.  On Superuser you should specify on which version(s) of Windows some particular instruction will work.  Etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
all=$( cat file1 file2 )
echo "$all" > file2
```

only works with small-ish files.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Jasen's answer, this is a basis for a utility.

The code *sponge* in package [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) is designed to allow an in-place capability to almost any program, albeit externally. Essentially it soaks up input from STDIN and then writes the collected output to a filename, but NOT with re-direction.

We liked the idea, so we created a work-alike that collects data in memory, as opposed to a file as the real sponge does.

Here is a snippet of shell script to illustrate this:

```
# Utility functions: print-as-echo, print-line-with-visual-space.
pe() { for _i;do printf "%s" "$_i";done; printf "\n"; }
pl() { pe;pe "-----" ;pe "$*"; }

pl " Input files data2, data3:"
head data[23]
pe
ls -gGli data[23]

pl " Results, re-write file from memory, preserving inode:"
cat data[23] | ./absorb-memory-public data3
head -v data3
pe
ls -gGli data3
```

Producing:

```
-----
 Input files data2, data3:
==> data2 <==
hello world
hello bangladesh 

==> data3 <==
Dhaka in Bangladesh
Dhaka is capital of Bangladesh  

1051395 -rw-r--r-- 1 30 Jan  7 08:58 data2
1052221 -rw-r--r-- 1 53 Jan  7 08:58 data3

-----
 Results, re-write file from memory, preserving inode:
==> data3 <==
hello world
hello bangladesh 
Dhaka in Bangladesh
Dhaka is capital of Bangladesh  

1052221 -rw-r--r-- 1 83 Jan  7 08:58 data3
```

The core perl code is quite short (especially without error checking, the addition of which may be desirable):

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Carp;

# Avoid hang for argument matching "-version","--version", etc.
exit(0) if @ARGV && $ARGV[0] =~ /-version/;

my ( $file, $f, $memory );
$file = shift || croak("Need a filename.");

$/ = 0777;      # Slurp the entire STDIN
$memory = do { local $/; <> };

open( $f, ">", $file ) || die " Cannot open file \"$file\" for write.\n";

print $f "$memory";
```

Run on a system like:

```
OS, ker|rel, machine: Linux, 3.16.0-4-amd64, x86_64
Distribution        : Debian 8.9 (jessie) 
bash GNU bash 4.3.30
perl 5.20.2
```

Best wishes ... cheers, drl